# What format is this date value in?

Tags: javascript, json

Here's a forecast for London, GB from the [Open Weather Map](http://openweathermap.org) in JSON format.

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id=524901
```

Each list item in the JSON has a key within it called `dt` that looks like `"dt":1399626000`

I haven't done this before, so how do I figure out what format (unix timestamp?) and timezone `dt` is in (e.g. GMT, UTC), and how to translate the `dt` into a human-friendly format.

Comment: *"How to translate the dt into a human-friendly format"* http://momentjs.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I'm on the right page, the API documentation says [here](http://bugs.openweathermap.org/projects/api/wiki/Weather_Data) that it's a GMT Unix timestamp:

> dt | Time of data receiving in unixtime GMT

To convert it into a human-readable format using JavaScript, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript).